# How to swap two vectors in a mutable struct

Tags: rust

There is the following struct:

```
struct Data {
    xs: Vec<i32>,
    ys: Vec<i32>
}
```

At attempt to assign one vector of the struct to the other as follows leads to an error:

```
impl Data {
    fn proc(&mut self) {
        self.xs = self.ys;
    }
}
```

The error is `move occurs because self.ys has type Vec<i32>, which does not implement the Copy trait`.

The struct is borrowed as mutable, why it is not possible to move from `self.ys` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.swap.html) to swap the values in-place:

```rust
impl Data {
    fn proc(&mut self) {
        std::mem::swap(&mut self.xs, &mut self.ys);
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6f3c54818ec724b7b932de2e03882cbb)

`self.xs = self.ys` doesn't work because `Vec` doesn't implement `Copy`: you'd have to `.clone()` `ys`.

Comment: oh, beat me for the sec

Comment: Thank you, it does work. However, I don't understand why the `Copy` is required there. For example, it's possible to move from one mutable vector to another one once the vectors are defined as local variables in a function. Why this doesn't work once the vectors are in a struct?

Comment: @JoeDoe, you can not move from a `&mut self`

Comment: @Netwave So it's not possible to move value from any field of a struct that is borrowed as `&mut`, right? And, if yes,is it made in order to prevent any possibility to leave uninitialized value in a field. I'm curious that it is possible to drop the value from `ys` by assigning say a Vec::new() to it, but it is not possible to make the discarded value useful (i.e. use it as r-value).

Comment: @JoeDoe your guess is right more or less. Reassigning is ok, then the older value would be dropped. Or use `std::mem::take` to take ownership of the old value replacing it with a default or something. But in the end you is the same as doing mem::swap

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to @Smitop answer you can **`move`** into a new swaped `Data`. Notice that you cannot move from a `&mut` so the signature would have to change too:

```rust
impl Data {
    fn proc(self) -> Self {
        Self {
            xs: self.ys, ys: self.xs
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=51cfe49279c5ca5eff535dadcc842ea5)